# How to convert '31/12/18' to type Date with TSQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I tired this

```
select CONVERT(DATE, '31/12/18', 103) as rDatum
```

but I get error:

```
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

What is the right way to convert string which is date with short year to DATE in TSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY

INSERT INTO targetTable (rDatum, col2 etc)
SELECT CAST(someDate AS DATE) , col2 etc
FROM sourceTable
```

Comment: No, you should ever use the third parameter together with `CONVERT`. Your approach might work , but can have unexpected side effects as it will affect the whole batch. Furthermore you cannot use this inlined. Bad for VIEWs or iTVFs...

Comment: hmm, I need to insert data into a table. Where do i put the date format command?

Comment: @Shnugo why is that?

Comment: @Cool_Br33ze Your suggestion shows clearly, that you do not bother about specific (scope-tight) conversion hints. You rely on implicit conversion and you solve this with a general `SET DATEFORMAT` *anywhere before the insert*. But this will have an effect for each and any place where a date-value needs conversion to (or from) a string. If you do not re-set this after the insert (in this case you should buffer the actual value!) this will remain active. This is *procedural thinking*. Although it is okay for a *one time action* you should use the third parameter of `CONVERT` instead.

Comment: @Cool_Br33ze, your edit using `CAST(... AS DATE)` is - in this point of view - even worse than it was before... One should **never rely on implicit conversions with date/time values**...

Answer (score 4):

You were very close...

This is [british/french format with a 2-digit year](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).The format code is `3` (`103` is with a 4-digit year)

Try this

```
select CONVERT(DATE, '31/12/18', 3) as rDatum
```

Comment: It fails without the setting "SET DATEFORMAT DMY"

Comment: @Vlad I could not believe this and tried it once more. This works even if you use `'SET DATEFORMAT` with a wrong value. `CONVERT()` will not look at the default settings, when the third parameter is specified. I cannot test this with v2008 at the moment, but I doubt, that this would make any difference. This is the sole meaning of the third parameter...